# Ansible Template: Trying to index into a two level list

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, I'm trying to template out apache virtual host configurations, one per file.

I've got a jinja template that contains this:

```
...
DocumentRoot {{ mydomain.DocumentRoot }}
...
```

And I've got a playbook that calls the template,which contains:

```
vars:
  domain1:
    DocumentRoot: /var/www/html/domain1
  domain2: 
    DocumentRoot: /var/www/html/domain2
```

I want to be able to push out this template choosing between domain1 and domain2 to select the DocumentRoot (and other variables not shown)

So I need to somehow write in my template that mydomain should be substituted with 'domain1' or 'domain2'.

Among other things, I tried

```
ansible-playbook myplaybook.yml  -e mydomain=domain1
```

with no luck.

I need some sort of variable indirection, but I don't know how to write it, or even if it's possible.

I know that I should be able to iterate over the contents of an array, so why can't I construct a simple indirection.

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to create a list of dictionaries. For example

```yaml
  vars:
    apache_vhost:
      - ServerName: domain1
        DocumentRoot: /var/www/html/domain1
      - ServerName: domain2
        DocumentRoot: /var/www/html/domain2
```

Then the task below

```yaml
- template:
    src: vhost.j2
    dest: "{{ apache_conf_path }}/extra/{{ item.ServerName }}.conf"
  loop: "{{ apache_vhost }}"
  notify: reload apache
```

and the template

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName {{ item.ServerName }}
     DocumentRoot {{ item.DocumentRoot }}
     </VirtualHost>
```

would create files with the configuration of the virtual hosts in the directory `extra`. See [example](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-apache/blob/master/tasks/httpd-vhosts.yml) how to create the files, directories for virtual hosts, and include the extra files in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: This was the approach I used. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditions in your template to set the `DocumentRoot` according to the value of `mydomain`.

One of the simple ways is to use the value of `mydomain` in the **template** directly, if that is the only configuration:

Example:

```jinja
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/{{ mydomain }}
```

Depending on what you pass with `-e mydomain=`, this will result in:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
```

OR

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
```

Or if there are other parameters specific to domain, you can have conditions inside the **template**. Consider the example template below:

```jinja
{% if mydomain == 'domain1' %}
OtherSettings xyz
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/{{ mydomain }}
{% elif mydomain == 'domain2' %}
OtherSettings abc
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/{{ mydomain }}
{% endif %}
```

When you run the playbook with `-e "mydomain=domain1"`, it will render the first two lines. And for `domain2` it will match `elif` statement and render the appropriate lines.